# Response already committed doBeforeRender response.sendRedirect() (HippoCMS)

Tags: java, hippocms

In a get request for a page I read some session parameters. If some session parameters are missing I would like to redirect to home page or any page.

I tried doing that but obviously the response has been already committed before the doBeforeRender invocation.

Where should I do my redirect instead?

EDITED:
One way might to do it via javascript in the freemarker template.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the `doAction` method.

Comment: yeah it works in the doAction() but... I have a multi step workflow and I want to prohibit to access step 3 directly. this would definately happen if the user would access step3 directly via an url.

Answer (score 0):

I used `response.forward(path);` in my project and it worked.
The path is relative to the site root.

Hope it helps.